# Issue with deleting a SharePoint 2013 document library folder through call up menu

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server, folder

Recently some of our users reported an issue in which they are receiving an error message as shown below while trying to delete a folder from a document library using the call up menu associated with the folder.

Error 
Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.

### Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Go back to site

The folder is getting deleted but somehow it shows the error message before it gets deleted. Error message will not be showing if they delete it from the 'Files' option available at the top ribbon menu. Issue is with only some particular users. Among those affected, one person is a site collection admin and the rest are having 'Contribute' access. Tried revoking the access and adding again, cleared the browser cache, tried using different browsers(IE, Chrome and Firefox), but issue still persist.

Comment: Have you checked the logs ?